# Show that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial, $|p(x)|$ attains its minimum.

Tags: calculus

> Show that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial, $|p(x)|$ attains its minimum.

**Attempt**

Let $p(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$. Then if $|p(x)| =  |a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0|$. If $x > 0,$ then $|p(x)| = |a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0| \leq |a_n|x^n+|a_{n-1}|x^{n-1}+\cdots+|a_1|x+|a_0|.$ Then we can take there derivative of $|p(x)|$ to get a bound to find critical points. I am not sure how to deal with the case of $x \leq 0$.

Comment: First of all, $|p(x)|$ is not (usually) differentiable; secondly, just because $|a_n| x^n + ... + |a_0|$ attains a minimum doesn't imply that $p$ does.

Comment: @T.Bongers I didn't say it was differentiable and since $|a_n|x^n+\cdots+|a_0|$ attains a minimum implies $p$ does. I said the word bound.

Comment: Show that $|p(x)|$ is continuous and that $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} |p(x)| = \infty$ and deduce that the minimum is obtained in $[-R,R]$ for some $R$. Then use some known property of continuous functions and extemal points to finish it off.

Comment: @Puzzled417 You said "then we can take the derivative of $|p(x)|$," which is what I'm commenting about. And giving an upper bound on $|p|$ that attains a minimum is *not* sufficient.

Comment: @T.Bongers I meant take the derivative on the bound.

Comment: @Puzzled417 Ok, that's better. But again, that's not sufficient at *all*: There are many functions that are bounded by, say, $x + 1$ that do not attain a minimum.

Comment: I absolutely do not understand this question.  If $p(x_0) < 0$ for any $x_0$ then $|p(x)| \ge 0$ does *not* obtain the minimum.  if $p(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ the $|p(x)| = p(x)$ and the question is trivial.  And if $p$ is of odd degree.  then p has no min or max.   I dont get this question.

Comment: @fleablood So are you asking for example $p(x) = (x-1)^2-1$, the minimum here is $-1$ but the minimum of $|p(x)|$ is 0?

Comment: @fleablood The question does not ask to show that $|p(x)|$ attains the minimum of $p(x)$ but that $|p(x)|$ attains it's own minimum. The function $|p(x)|$ is bounded below by $0$ so the greatest lower bound $\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|p(x)| = a$ exist. To show that the minimum is attained we need to show that there is $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|p(x)| = a$. That being said I see that the the wording "attains it's minimum" can be confusing here.

Comment: Okay.  That makes more sense.  But is it a known condition that any continuous function that is bounded below and tends to infinity (or even any value that isn't it's minimum) reaches its minimum?

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292714/proof-that-a-continuous-function-is-bounded-below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

observe that if the lead coefficient is $c_n x^n$ then for $|x|$ large we have
$$
|p(x)| \geq |c_n/2| |x|^{n}.
$$
So for some large $R$ the value on $|x|>R$ is greater than $|p(0)|.$

This means that the minimum can only be attained and approached on $|x| \leq R.$ So it's enough to work on the set $|x|\leq R.$ However, a continuous function on a compact set always attains its minimum, we are done.

Comment: Why is $|p(x)| \geq (c_n/2) |x|^{n}$ true for large $x$?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Write $$|p(x)| = |c_nx^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} \ldots + c_0| = |c_n x^n|\cdot\left|1 + \frac{c_{n-1}}{c_n x} + \ldots + \frac{c_0}{c_n x^n}\right|$$ When $|x|\to\infty$ the last factor above goes to $1$. Pick $R$ so large that each of the terms $\frac{c_{n-i}}{c_n x^i}$ is less than $\frac{1}{2n}$ in absolute value when $x = R$ then we have $|p(x)| > |c_n x^n|/2$ for all $|x|>R$.

Comment: @Winther What is the point of saying So for some large $R$ the value on $|x| > R$ is greater than $|p(0)|$ and why is it true?

Comment: @user19405892 The point is that since $|p(x)| > |p(0)|$ for $|x|>R$ the minimum cannot be attained for $|x|>R$. You can pick for example $1$ instead of $0$ if you want. It's true since the inequality Mark has given here shows that $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty} |p(x)| = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $q(x)=\mid p(x)\mid^2$ it is a polynomial of even degree, its derivative has an odd degree. This implies $lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}q'(x)=-\infty$ $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}q'(x)=+\infty$. So there exists $a<0, b>0, a<b$ such that $q'(x)<0, x<a$ and $q'(x)>0, x>b$. Thus $p^2(x)$ is a decreasing function on $(-\infty,a]$ and an increasing function on $[b,+\infty)$. The minimum of the restriction of $p^2$ to $[a,b]$ exists and its square root is the minimum of $\mid p(x)\mid$.

Comment: there is no need for $a<0<b$.

Answer (score 0):

Does $|p(x)|$ always attain $p(x)$'s minimum?

Try using a $p(x)$ such that $a_0<0$ and $a_0$ happens to be its minimum [example: $p(x)=x^2-1$]. Then $|p(x)|$ will never attain $a_0$, but $|a_0|$.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. Try to word it better.

Comment: It says: "show that $|p(x)|$ obtains it's minimum" and *not* that $|p(x)|$'s minimum is the same as that of $p(x)$. What this mean is that we need to show that there exist a $x_*\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|p(x_*)|$ is the minimum value of $|p(x)|$.

Comment: @Winther How can't a function obtain its own minimum? Isn't that the definition of a minimum is the smallest value the function reaches?

Comment: @Puzzled417 It's your question so you should clarify if I'm mistaken here (and I will delete my comments), but the standard interpretation of the phrase "$|p(x)|$ attains it's minimum" is what I explained above: there exist a value $x_*\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|p(x_*)|$ is the minimum value of $|p(x)|$.

Comment: @Winther Oh I am sorry, I see what you mean. Of course if the function were not bounded it wouldn't so we need only check that.

Comment: @Puzzled417 And also if we are not talking about polynomials then it does not need to be true. For example $f(x) = e^{x}$ does not attain it's minimum value $0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The key property that makes it true for polynomials is continuity + the fact that $|p(x)| \to \infty$ as $|x|\to \infty$.

Comment: @Winther Do you mind posting an answer?